# ipywidgets: Automatically update variable and run code after altering widget value

Tags: jupyter-notebook, ipython, ipywidgets

I have been trying to automatically update a variable and run a code snippet after altering a ipywidget.

So far the only partial solution I have found is to declare a global variable kind of following the example on the github ([here](https://github.com/jupyter-widgets/ipywidgets/issues/1947)):

```
import ipywidgets as widgets
from IPython.display import display
x = 5
slider = widgets.IntSlider()
slider.value = x
def on_change(v):
   global x
   x = v['new'] 
slider.observe(on_change, names='value')
display(slider)
```

Ideally what I am trying to achieve is to automatically change the x value after altering the widget without the use of global variables and also change some previously defined variables. It would be something like this:

```
x = 5
y = []
slider = widgets.IntSlider()
slider.value = x
def on_change(v):
   x = v['new']
   y.append(x)
slider.observe(on_change, names='value')
display(slider)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way to achieve this would to be to make a class that accepts the new widget value, and does the derived calculation as well. I've done a simple addition but you could append to a list.

```python
import ipywidgets as widgets

class Updated:

    def __init__(self):
        self.widget_value = None
        self.derived_value = None

    def update(self, val_dict) -> None:
        self.widget_value = val_dict['new']
        self.derived_value = self.widget_value + 10

update_class = Updated()

x = 5
y = []
slider = widgets.IntSlider()
slider.value = x

def on_change(v):
    update_class.update(v)
slider.observe(on_change, names='value')
display(slider)
```

You can then see how `update_class.widget_value` and `update_class.derived_value` change as you move the slider.